# retrieve SMS history from Twilio API from specific number

Tags: php, sms, twilio

using twilio, trying to return a list of text messages sent to a specific number...with no luck

```
foreach ( $client->account->sms_messages->To(+12345678901) as $sms ) {  echo $sms->body;    echo "</br>"; }
```

the problem is obviously the "To(+12345678901)"

I have tried using single and double quotes, numbers owned and not owned, and several other parameter formatting options, I cant seem to get lucky here. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

You've almost got it. The part you're missing is using the getIterator method for filtering. You pass this an array containing the data you're filtering on. Here's a code snippet:

```
foreach ($client->account->messages->getIterator(0, 50, array(
    'To' => '+12345678901',
)) as $message) {
    echo "From: {$message->from}\nTo: {$message->to}\nBody: " . $message->body;
}
```

You can read a bit more about [filtering messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sms?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon#list-get-filters) in our docs. The docs for our [PHP helper library](https://twilio-php.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/rest/messages.html?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon#filtering-messages) also have some good examples.

Comment: that did the trick, the problem is my 1 day understanding of php...thanks again so much